# Android. Определение и показ чувствительности микрофона

Tags: android, графика

Добрый день! Мне необходимо графически (в принципе любой способ подойдет) определять и показывать чувствительность микрофона, точнее децибеллы, которые идут при записи на его вход... хотя бы просто.. есть голос, нет голоса.. уровни.. не могу найти и существует ли такой функционал. Использую AudioRecord.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/64000/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class SoundMeter {

    private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;

    public void start() {
            if (mRecorder == null) {
                    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                    mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null"); 
                    mRecorder.prepare();
                    mRecorder.start();
            }
    }

    public void stop() {
            if (mRecorder != null) {
                    mRecorder.stop();       
                    mRecorder.release();
                    mRecorder = null;
            }
    }

    public double getAmplitude() {
            if (mRecorder != null)
                    return  mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
            else
                    return 0;

    }
}
```

Когда нужно получить уровень, вызывайте `SoundMeter.getAmplitude();`
Выводить значение вы можете, например, в `ProgressBar`.
Если надо получать это значение все время, сожете сделать это в бусконечном цикле, предварительно вынеся код в background поток

Comment: @Fox, если помогло - отметте ответ, как правильный, спасибо на хлеб не намажешь...